# How do you say "breast meat chicken"?

Tags: translation, food

My instructor told me to say 「胸肉」-- "breast meat" -- but we got a lot of weird looks in Japan (one waitress asked for clarification by discreetly tracing the shape of her own breast). Since that translation was not very helpful, what's the more common expression?

Comment: `(one waitress asked for clarification by discreetly tracing the shape of her own breast)` 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean this type of chicken meat?

[image: 胸肉]

Then it's (鳥)胸肉 (むねにく【LHLL】). I don't know how to call it in other ways. If it wasn't understood, it's either because you misread the kanji or because your pronunciation was inaccurate.

If it's clear that you're talking about a type of chicken (for example, if you're at a *yakitori* restaurant), just saying むね【LH】 is enough.

Comment: I hadn't learned about pitch accent yet, so maybe that was the problem.